# Regex pattern for Swift with some differences

Tags: swift, regex, macos

So I'm having some issues with setting up the correct regular expression for finding a specific set of strings within a file. The gist of what I'm trying to do is we have a file filled with a bunch of functions that are used across different platforms. Problem is there are numerous duplicates and/or alternates that can be blown away but I want to parse out all of the other functions to just focus on this one set. Below is an example of the functions I'm trying to find in the file (there aren't the exact functions, just a quick example)

```
searchForKey(key: "some_key_name", defaultValue: "Random message")
searchForKey(key: "other_key", defaultValue: "A long message here")
```

So I found a site that can build a regex but it looks like it's for PHP since it didn't work when I tried in swift. Here's what it looked like but as I said I keep getting a failure in finding a match.

```
let pattern = "searchForKey(key:.*, defaultValue:.*)"
let result = testKey.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) == nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should know first is that special characters like `(` or `)` need to be escaped in regex patterns. Regex escaping character `\` becomes `\\` in Swift String. (You need escaping even in PHP.)

```
let text = """
searchForKey(key: "some_key_name", defaultValue: "Random message")
searchForKey(key: "other_key", defaultValue: "A long message here")
"""

let pattern = "searchForKey\\(key:.*, defaultValue:.*\\)"
if let range = text.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
    print("Found:", text[range])
} else {
    print("Not Found")
}
//-> Found: searchForKey(key: "some_key_name", defaultValue: "Random message")
```

But it may be better to use `*?` instead of simple `*`. Sometimes simple `.*` may match longer than you expect:

```
let text2 = """
searchForKey(key: "some_key_name", defaultValue: "Random message");searchForKey(key: "other_key", defaultValue: "A long message here")
"""

if let range = text2.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
    print("Found:", text2[range])
} else {
    print("Not Found")
}
//-> Found: searchForKey(key: "some_key_name", defaultValue: "Random message");searchForKey(key: "other_key", defaultValue: "A long message here")

let pattern2 = "searchForKey\\(key:.*?, defaultValue:.*?\\)"
if let range = text2.range(of: pattern2, options: .regularExpression) {
    print("Found:", text2[range])
} else {
    print("Not Found")
}
//-> Found: searchForKey(key: "some_key_name", defaultValue: "Random message")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, makes sense and helped clear up what I was missing.